# Spaces desktop missing when turning off external display, how to get them back?

Tags: display, spaces

My Macbook Pro (Big Sur 11.6) is connected to an external display and I make frequent use of multiple desktops, distributed among the Macbook and the display for convenience.

Now, when I disconnect the external display, I cannot access the desktops that were located in it from my Macbook. When I reconnect the display, I regain access to them though.

Is there a way to access/reassign them from my Macbook when the external display is disconnected?

Comment: You describe two different scenarios - turning the display off & disconnecting it. Which is it? Do you have 'displays have separate spaces' enabled in mission control prefs?

Comment: I just pull out the HDMI connector. "Displays have separate spaces" is enabled.

Comment: Then those Spaces should move to the primary display. A Space has no affinity to a given display & you should be able to call them to either display.

Comment: Pull them how? That's not what I experience. If I move a space from my laptop to the display, it remains there, and there's no way for me to pull it to my MacBook unless I reconnect the display.

Comment: OK. This isn't a mode I ever use, but I've just tested it extensively. Disconnecting one display pulls all windows & spaces back to the other after a reboot, except for the highest number [idk why this is, it didn't have any app open on it which might be a reason]. Nothing is 'lost'.

Comment: Why would I have to reboot my computer to disconnect my external display...?

Comment: So the computer can enumerate the displays properly. I assume by your surprise that you have the monitors connected by some method which you consider ought to be completely hot-swappable. Some are. Many aren't. Hot-swapping displays is not as simple as they'd have you believe.